# Retrofit MVVM delay in response

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, retrofit2, android-livedata

I implemented a recycler view in a fragment which will be updated based on the text entered in searchview. As soon a text entered in searchview which is in MainActivity. I'm calling onQueryTextChange(enteredText) in repository and fetching data from API based on the text entered. it happens in realtime

**The Problem :**

I'm unable to return the data fetched from repositoty as soon as i call the queryTextChange in repository which will call the api and set the data to the mutablelive data and returns the live data. but im getting null value from repository as the api call takes some time to fetch the data. How do i solve this issue to achieve what i wanted.

**I'm currently trying to achieve this via..**

MainActivity --> contains Searchview
Fragment --> contains recyclerview

MainActivity

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            model.queryTextChange(query,getString(R.string.api_key));
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            
            model.queryTextChange(newText,getString(R.string.api_key));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My View Model:

```
private String API_KEY = "";

// This is observed from fragment
public MutableLiveData<SearchGifs> gifList = new MutableLiveData<>();


public HomeViewModel(String api_key) {
    this.API_KEY = api_key;
}

GifRepo gifRepo = new GifRepo();


public void queryTextChange(String text, String key){

    //Calls the repo and updates the mutablelivedata which is observed from fragment
     gifList.postValue(gifRepo.queryTextChange(text,key).getValue());
}
```

Repository :

```
public MutableLiveData<SearchGifs> queryTextChange(String text, String api_key) {

    MutableLiveData<SearchGifs> list = new MutableLiveData<>();

    Call<SearchGifs> gifSearch = service.search(api_key,text);

    gifSearch.enqueue(new Callback<SearchGifs>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SearchGifs> call, Response<SearchGifs> response) {
            //getting data here perfectly
            list.postValue(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SearchGifs> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    //doesn't wait for api call and returning null
    return list;

}
```

Fragment: (Where it should update the recyclerview)

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    //Not Getting triggered 
    model.gifList.observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<SearchGifs>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(SearchGifs gifs) {
       
            //RecyclerViewData will be updated here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you return data using interface/callbacks?

Comment: i'm not really sure what you're asking, because yes, api calls take time to complete, there's no way of having this be instant or synchronous

Comment: I need to find a way to send data back or a callback when network call is finished  to view model from repository and update the livedata object in Viewmodel as per MVVM pattern.